# self bot house or name changing

Tags: discord, discord.py

When I try to use

```
@bot.command()
async def house(ctx):
    await bot.user.edit(house="Brilliance")
```

It raises an error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Password is required
```

How can I login with email and password?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the password:

```py
@bot.command()
async def house(ctx):
    await bot.user.edit(house="Brilliance", password="my password")
```